# Why does my AWS EC2 Instance terminates when stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

Everytime I stop my AWS EC2 instance, it terminates automatically with a few seconds. Additionally a new instance is created. Can anyone suggest why this would be happening?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html), Amazon gives you fairly fine control over how and when your instances are terminated.

Comment: I know.. but it is not a=happening.. My instance is terminated automatically after I stop it.

Comment: How do you know this? Does your ec2 console say "Terminated" after stopping?

Comment: after stopping its states stopped...2-3 sec later when i refresh its states terminated

Comment: Was your instance created through Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: This can happen if you have enabled any services which automatically create instances for you. Like open spot requests.

Comment: @david no initially I tried through ec2 then beanstalk.. I had the same prob in both the cases.

Answer (score 17):

Because it is part of an Auto Scaling group.

According to AWS Support, it is normal behavior to Terminate an instance when you tell it to Stop if it is part of an Auto Scaling group.
My Termination Protection was set to Stop but apparently it overrides this setting.

In order to Stop an instance that's part of a Auto Scaling group and NOT Terminate it, you must Detach it from the Auto Scaling group before stopping it:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/detach-instance-asg.html

I just went through this

Comment: It'd be good if you could add a link to the AWS support page you found this on

Comment: why?! whyyyyy??!!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the **shutdown behavior** of your EC2 instance when creating it.

Selecting some options will default and/or force you to termination on stop.

See EC2's documentation for more information.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html