# Mesososphere DCOS cluster on AWS. EC2 instances are terminated and again restarted after they are stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, mesos, mesosphere

I have created a Mesosphere DCOS cluster on AWS using the DCOS template. I want to stop the instances after the day end. But after stopping the instances they are terminated and replaced by new instances. Please suggest how to stop the instances.

If the EC2 instances are detached from the auto scaling groups, is the functioning of the DCOS cluster hampered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fully shut down the cluster, follow the steps in the [docs](https://docs.mesosphere.com/install/removeaws/), which means deleting the CloudFormation stack as well as removing the S3 bucket that contains config data.

UPDATE: since the OP made it clear that the underlying motivation is to 'pause' the cluster over night in order to cut down on costs, I'm clarifying hereby that this is not possible, currently. In order to keep the configuration data around while minimizing the costs you can [scale the DCOS cluster down](https://support.mesosphere.com/hc/en-us/articles/204622489-How-can-I-scale-my-DCOS-cluster-in-AWS-), for a certain period of time.

Comment: I want to just stop the instances (so as to not get billed for the nightly hours). Is this possible? I don't want to lose the configuration data

Comment: Sorry, this is at the current point in time not possible. You can scale it down, though. I'll update the answer. Please vote/flag as correct once I've done this so other people that have the same use case directly get the right answer, @rajasi.

Answer (score 0):

I found this is the instance behaviour when a server is part of an autoscaling group. Remove the servers from the autoscaling groups then you can stop them. You can add them back later.

[Why does my AWS EC2 Instance terminates when stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194893/why-does-my-aws-ec2-instance-terminates-when-stopped)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/detach-instance-asg.html

Luck!